# How to FTP in Java

Tags: java, apache, ftp, java-io

I'm trying to download files through FTPS, the result file is always empty. 
(I'm using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient)

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient( );
OutputStream outStream;

client.connect("ip");
client.login("user", "pass");

String remoteFile = "filePath";
outStream = new FileOutputStream( "destinationFile" );
client.retrieveFile(remoteFile, outStream);
outStream.flush();
```

Comment: maybe you should close the outstream?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSch Java library is a good option for your problem

Comment: i gave you +1 but someone else gave you -1 ... how can I accept?